# Drupal relative link problems moving from mydomain.com/test to mydomain.com

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, tinymce, wysiwyg

I currentley have a test site up and running on mydomain.cm/test. I am using the WYSIWYG module with tinymce to allow my customers to upload pictures to the site. One a image is added to the site tinymce/imce does not use the base url defined for the site in front opf links but gives linkes realtive to the root i.e. a picture of img.jpg will be linked in the code as /test/img.jpg. When the site goes live and we lose the /test the img will no longer be found there.

What would be the best way to bulk upload all the links before going live to remove /test in front of the links?

In the future when settting up a test site I will user a subdmain instead so I will not have this issue.

Any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to run a MySQL query directly on your database. Just search and replace in your node_revisions table in both the body and teasers column.

```
update node_revisions set body = replace(body,'/test/','/');
update node_revisions set teaser = replace(teaser,'/test/','/');
```

Of course, backup before you do this.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to leave all your content untouched and rewrite all the `/test/*.[jpg,gif,png]` urls through a rewrite rule in .htaccess.